# Empty Form Request Data?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a form:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('news.store') }}">
```

This links to my resource controller, in the store method I have:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    dd($request->all());
    ....
```

But this outputs an empty array.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Do you properly include CSRF protection in your form? I think you'd be getting an error from Laravel if it was not the case, but better ask just to be sure.

Comment: Ah yes, no token! How can I include this, i know a hidden field, but how can I output the token in L5.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#csrf-protection

Comment: include this before starting of class use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Comment: I've used {{ csrf_field() }} but the value of the input is empty?

Comment: Show us whole form please.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, laravel would throw a `TokenMismatchException` if this had anything to do with a missing CSRF field. 
Secondly, in laravel 5.2, you add CSRF field this way: `{!! csrf_field !!}`.
Lastly, verify that you have a post route.